# What's the best CPU and motherboard under $300 for playing Minecraft?

Tags: processor, motherboard, gaming, desktop

What is the best CPU and motherboard under $300 for playing the Java Edition of Minecraft?
I already have a graphics card, 256GB SSD and a 600W PSU.
I'll also use it for normal computer usage.

Comment: You haven't mentioned RAM. Does that also need to be included in your $300 budget? Also, are you going to be hosting servers, LAN or internet, and which edition of Minecraft? (Java or Bedrock?)

Comment: I don't have RAM, but it's included separately from this budget. And I'm only going to be playing Minecraft, sometimes with a few friends and on servers. Also, I'll be using Java Edition.

Comment: I will do a little more research to write a full answer later, but I am going to suggest the [Ryzen 5 2600](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-2600#product-specs) (~ $200 USD) and a B450 motherboard. That will definitely land around $300 or less and it would be fast enough to handle many other games, only your GPU would be holding you back then. Also, this is in USD right?

Comment: Yes, it is in USD.

Comment: What graphics card are you using?
A Ryzen 5 2600 or 3600 might well be overkill.

Also, if you're looking for performance, the Java edition is definitely not optimal.

Comment: I have a GTX 1050 Ti. I don't like Bedrock Edition very much, which is why I use Java Edition. Most of the people I play with use Java Edition too.

Comment: @towe, Why would it be *overkill*? Why would you not suggest the fastest CPU possible for the given budget? (Maybe even faster than the 2600 if a good deal can be found.) If they ever intend to upgrade their GPU the CPU would eventually be put to good use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Processor:** `AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Processor with Wraith Stealth Cooler - YD2600BBAFBOX` - $115

**Motherboard:** `Asus Prime B450M-A/CSM AMD Ryzen 2 AM4 DDR4 HDMI DVI VGA M.2 USB 3.1 Gen2 mATX Motherboard` $77

**Links provided below to buy these products**

Processor: [Link to buy the processor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B41WS48)

Motherboard: [Link to buy the motherboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FKV5HWJ)

***NB: You can buy B450 motherboard from any decent brand***